Mouse control on Window
My friend's mouse on the screen frequently turns into this loading-like icon, he's not good at solving computer problems and neither am I. I'll be greatly appreciate if the community can help.
So far until I posted this question, I can't find enough informations about his problem on the internet. Whenever the problem occur, he can't do anything with his mouse so it'd be nice if we can find the solution.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
